# How to structure static javascript files in Node.js (Express) + Typescript application and what is the right way of using environment variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, model-view-controller

I am working on a Node.js (Express) + TypeScript application which implements the MVC pattern. This is how my project directory looks like

```
.
├── dist/
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public/
├── README.md
├── src/
│   ├── app.ts
│   ├── controllers/
│   ├── routes/
│   └── views/
└── tsconfig.json
```

Now, I know I can put all the static files like all the JS files for the client-side inside the `public` folder but that is if I am writing my application in JS. As I mentioned, I am using TypeScript for this application and want to write my client-side logic using TypeScript. But I don't know, for example, what should be the folder structure inside the `src` directory and also If I am marking the `public` folder (which is outside the `dist` folder) as static using `express.static()`, how can I tell the TS compiler to move the files for client-side code to the `public/js` directory, instead of putting it inside the `src` directory along with the server-side code.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir